# Should I amend my tax return to include my foreign bank account (US)?

Tags: taxes

I live in Asia. I made a wire transfer of about 50k from a US account to my spouse's account here. I filed taxes with TurboTax and did not click 'yes' to the question, 'Did you have a bank account in a foreign country?'

Based on the links below I think that I don't have to amend my return based on the 400k limit for expats.  Am I correct?

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/do-i-need-to-file-form-8938-statement-of-specified-foreign-financial-assets
https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/summary-of-fatca-reporting-for-us-taxpayers

Comment: Is it a joint account?

Comment: @littleadv it is not, but we are married filing jointly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You not needing to file form 8938 does not mean you do not have to answer Yes on [1040 Schedule B](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sb.pdf) line 7a ("At any time during 2022, did you have a financial interest in or signature authority over a financial account (such as a bank account, securities account, or brokerage account) located in a foreign country?"). Since you are married filing jointly, you need to answer Yes if either you or your spouse had a foreign account at some point in the year.

Furthermore, since your wife had more than $10,000 in foreign accounts at some point in the year, you guys need to answer Yes to line 7b ("re you required to file FinCEN Form 114, Report of Foreign Bank and Financial
Accounts (FBAR), to report that financial interest or signature authority?"), answer line 8, and she needs to file [FBAR](https://bsaefiling.fincen.treas.gov/NoRegFBARFiler.html) for the year.

Comment: +1: Schedule B and FBAR is where most people fail. Form 8938 has much higher thresholds for reporting, especially for those living abroad.

Comment: I think there should be one slight change to your great answer - let me know if I'm wrong please.  Since I transferred from my USA bank account to my spouse's (not joint) foreign account, I think only she hass to file FBAR.

Comment: @Ken-EnoughaboutMonica: but that still means you had a foreign account, with the max value being at least $50k, for some part of the year. So why wouldn't you have to file FBAR?

Comment: @user102008 - I did not - my wife did.  I sent the money from my US account to her foreign account.

Comment: @Ken-EnoughaboutMonica: corrected